# Вывод по условию из многомерного массива

Tags: php

Возникла потребность искать и выводить информацию по условию ( в данной ситуации значение 15185211, но как видно в коде из примера оно находится в разных ключах. float_value - первый массив и value - второй массив.) из ['attributes']. Возникла заминка в обращении к ['attributes'] так как он находится в массивах которые php сам нумерует после декодирования из формата JSON. Мой пример из примера получил последовательный номер 65( и дальше там такие же массивы с последовательными номера 0,2,3,4 ... 66, 67, 68... 333 и т.д.) Таких массивом много и количество их меняется. И я не могу разобраться как указать такие массивы автоматически а не вручную вбивать каждый номер массива хотя и это нереально так как количество каждый раз разное.
К примеру $items_array = $backpack_data['result']['items'][*как указать все 
пронумерованные массивы, если их количество не известно*]['attributes'];

Сейчас я использую этот код для выборки данных из массивов по их ['defindex']. Ищем совпадение ['defindex'] из первого масива во втором и в случае успеха выводим дополнительную информацию (изображение, описание, уровень и т.д.) которая берется со второго массива и соответсвует совпавшему с первым значению ['defindex'].

```
$items_array = $backpack_data['result']['items']; // Первый массив
   $schema_array = $schema_data['result']['items']; // Второй массив

     foreach($items_array as $item)// Первый массив
    {
            foreach($schema_array as $schema_item)// Второй массив

                    if($schema_item['defindex'] == $item['defindex'])
                    {

                            echo '<img src="'.$schema_item['image_url'].'" title="'.$schema_item['item_name'].' '.$item['level'].' level">';
                            break;
                    }
     }
```

Так же не составило труда выводит информацию, к примеру по ['level']. Добавив условие if ($item['level'] == 100)

```
$items_array = $backpack_data['result']['items']; // Первый массив
   $schema_array = $schema_data['result']['items']; // Второй массив

  foreach($items_array as $item)// Первый массив
    {
            foreach($schema_array as $schema_item)// Второй массив

            if ($item['level'] == 100){

                    if($schema_item['defindex'] == $item['defindex'])
                    {

                            echo '<img src="'.$schema_item['image_url'].'" title="'.$schema_item['item_name'].' '.$item['level'].' level">';
                            break;
                    }
                    }
     }
```

Тут находим данные соответствующие условию, берем их ['defindex'] и дальше как выше ищем совпадение выводим информацию на страницу.

И я не могу разобратся ка указать такие массивы автоматически, а не вручную вбитать каждый номер массива хотя и это нереально так как количество каждый раз разное, и дальше как выше получить ['defindex'] подходящих по условию из ['attributes'] первого массива и сравнить со вторым массивом по ['defindex'].

Простите я не выложил исходные данные которые разбираю после декодирования с формата JSON:

Первый массив
 PHP:

```
Array ( [result] => Array (

[items] => Array (

[65] => Array (

  [id] => 2008542462
  [original_id] => 1057898213
  [defindex] => 617
  [level] => 10
  [quality] => 6
  [inventory] => 2147483947
  [quantity] => 1
  [origin] => 0
  [style] => 1

[attributes] => Array (
     [0] => Array (
       [defindex] => 142
       [value] => 1265087803
       [float_value] => 15185211
     )
     [1] => Array (
       [defindex] => 261
       [value] => 1265087803
       [float_value] => 15185211
     )
     [2] => Array (
       [defindex] => 292
       [value] => 1115684864
       [float_value] => 64
     )
     [3] => Array (
       [defindex] => 388
       [value] => 1115684864
       [float_value] => 64
     )
)
)
)
)
)
```

Второй массив ( для большего понимания )

```
    [1196] => Array (
   [name] => Paint Can 11
   [defindex] => 5037
   [item_class] => tool
   [item_type_name] => Инструмент
   [item_name] => Золотой
   [item_description] => Применяется для окрашивания предметов.
   [proper_name] => [model_player] => [item_quality] => 6
   [image_inventory] => backpack/player/items/crafting/paintcan
   [min_ilevel] => 5
   [max_ilevel] => 5
   [image_url] => /icons/paintcan.9046edf23b64960a4084dad29d05d2c902feec78.png
   [image_url_large] => /icons/paintcan_large.b8e71a4720fa96d963f45db61c013185ca637aa6.png
   [craft_class] => tool
   [craft_material_type] => tool

    [capabilities] => Array (
         [can_craft_mark] => 1
         [can_be_restored] => 1
         [strange_parts] => 1
         [can_card_upgrade] => 1
         [can_strangify] => 1
         [can_killstreakify] => 1
         [can_consume] => 1
     )
    [tool] => Array (
         [type] => paint_can
      [usage_capabilities] => Array (
         [paintable] => 1
       )
     )

    [used_by_classes] => Array ( )

    [attributes] => Array (
      [0] => Array (
         [name] => set item tint RGB
         [class] => set_item_tint_rgb
         [value] => 15185211
       )
     )  
 )
```

Comment: Добрый день. Беглый взгляд по вашему коду приводит к вопросам. Во-первых, почему у вас два условия загнанные в одинаковый перебор циклов выполняются дважды? Хотя это можно было бы упростить на мой взгляд. Второй момент, опять же происходит из первой проблемы: у Вас, я вижу, по первому совпадению условия срабатывает break. Для одного вывода echo из второго массива столько коду?) Если массивы объемные еще, то их несколько раз гонять нет смысла. Пишу по интуиции, хотя она может подводить меня). Я бы пересмотрел логику кода, а потом уже решал бы Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Моя вина. Я не указал пример данных которые разбираю.